# What is a continuous real valued function on the unit circle?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

"Let $g$ be a continuous real-valued function on the unit circle $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid ||x||=1\}$ so that $g(0,1) = g(1,0) = 0$ and $g(-x) = -g(x)$."

This is only the background information given on the main question. I have not been able to solve the question, probably because I am not sure what to make of this information. Can anybody explain what can be deduced from this?

Comment: How about $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: Other than the obvious (e.g. $g(0,-1)=0$, and knowing the value of $g$ on the upper half circle also gives you its values on the lower half circle) and the general stuff (e.g. a continuous function on a compact set must have a maximum value), there really isn't all that much you can say: the conditions you've given are very general.

Comment: A function of the angle like $\sin \theta$ generally works fine

Answer (score 1):

If you define any continuous function on the upper half of the circle which is zero at both end points then you can extend it to a continuous function on the whole circle by just setting f (-x)=-f (x). Furthermore all such functions have this form.

Answer (score 1):

That depends very much on what the question is. I'll give you some ideas.

The circle is a compact, so is its image. That means that the function reaches its maximum and its minimum, and every value in between. That is, the values of $g$ are precisely those inside some compact interval $[a,b]$. Since $g(-\mathbf{x})=-g(\mathbf x)$ for all $\mathbf x$, this interval must be centered on $0$, that is, $[-k,k]$ for some $k$.

$g$ needn't be $0$ everywhere. Take for example $g(x,y)=|x|y$.

If you tell us the question maybe we can be more helpful :)